# Displaying notification messages in angular2 app failes

Tags: angular

I want to implement notification messages for my simple angular 2 app. I decided to use `ng2-toasty`. My simple angular 2 app is based on [ng2-admin theme](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-admin/articles/012-project-structure/).

1. I installed package
   **`npm install ng2-toasty --save`**
2. Import and register ToastyModule in the AppModule

> ```
> import { ToastyModule } from 'ng2-toasty';
> ...
>  imports: [ 
>     ToastyModule.forRoot(),
> ]
> ```
>
> 3. Inside Component I import again Toast service and injected inside constructor

```
import { ToastyService, ToastyConfig, ToastOptions, ToastData } from 'ng2-toasty';
constructor(private toastyService: ToastyService) { }
... 
// This error is raised on purpose inside some method
this.toastyService.error({
      title: 'Error',
      msg: 'An unexpected error occured!',
      theme: 'default',
      showClose: true,
      timeout: 2000
});
```

Inside app.component.html
I added on top of the file

```
<ng2-toasty [position="'top-right'"]></ng2-toasty>
```

> I don't get any errors inside console but still notification message is not shown. 
>   I've found several examples where I need to update `systemjs.config.js` or `webpack.config.vendor.js` files but inside this template I cannot find one. What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line of code Inside app.component.html

```
<ng2-toasty [position] ="'top-right'"></ng2-toasty>
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your post

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you are trying to import a new module to your app, you just declare it in your app module (or any other module you wish to use it) and then use it.

In your case, ng toasty runs as a service as well, so you will need to import it as a provider too. In your app module providers[] array, add:

```
providers: [ToastyService] // add ToastyService
```

Comment: Thanks, I add ToastyService to the providers but I'm experiencing same thing. No errors but no notification messages also.